# Homebrew OpenCV installation: attempts to install gcc 5.2 which is already present

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I'm on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).
I'm trying to install OpenCV using Homebrew, but as soon as the installation starts, it starts installing gcc as a dependency.

> Installing opencv from homebrew/homebrew-science Installing
>   dependencies for homebrew/science/opencv: gcc, cmake, eige Installing
>   homebrew/science/opencv dependency: gcc Downloading
>   http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
>
> ......

The problem is, I already have gcc 5.2.0 installed via Homebrew:

```
gcc-5 --version
```

gives

> gcc-5 (Homebrew gcc5 5.2.0) 5.2.0

I tried poking inside the OpenCV formula, but I couldn't even find a mention of gcc there.

The same problem occurs when I try to install OpenCV 3.

Is there a workaround? I'd rather not have to install gcc 5.2 all over again.

### [I'll mention here that back when I installed gcc 5.2, I was running OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) - if it's at all relevant.]

This is the output of `brew info gcc`:

> `gcc: stable 5.2.0 (bottled) GNU compiler collection
>   https://gcc.gnu.org 
>   Not installed 
>   From:
>   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gcc.rb
>   ==> Dependencies Required: gmp ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔, isl ✔
>   ==> Options
>   --with-all-languages  Enable all compilers and languages, except Ada
>   --with-java   Build the gcj compiler
>   --with-jit    Build the jit compiler
>   --with-nls    Build with native language support (localization)
>   --without-fortran     Build without the gfortran compiler
>   --without-multilib    Build without multilib support
>   ==> Caveats GCC has been built with multilib support. Notably, OpenMP may not work:   https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60670 If
>   you need OpenMP support you may want to   brew reinstall gcc
>   --without-multilib`

Comment: What is the output of `brew info gcc`?

Comment: @bfontaine I have added the output of `brew info gcc` to my question. Wonder why it says "Not installed" there...

Comment: Thank you, and what is the output of `readlink $(which gcc-5)`?

Comment: It's `../Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/bin/gcc-5`

Comment: Thanks; I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gcc` you have is the `homebrew/versions/gcc5` formula, not the `gcc` (core) one. For now they install the same `gcc` version but `gcc5` will *always* install 5.x versions while `gcc` will install whatever is the latest version.

This is why it tries to install `gcc` because that formula is in fact not installed.

If you print the dependencies you see it it depends on `numpy` which in turn depends on `gcc`:

```
$ brew deps --tree opencv
homebrew/science/opencv (required dependencies)
├── cmake
├── pkg-config
├── jpeg
├── libpng
|   └── xz
├── libtiff
|   └── jpeg
├── eigen
|   └── cmake
├── openexr
|   ├── pkg-config
|   └── ilmbase
└── homebrew/python/numpy
    ├── :python3
    └── :gcc
```

`brew install opencv` supports a `--without-python` option which disables Python support so if you don’t need it you won’t have to install `gcc`:

```
$ brew deps --tree opencv --without-python
homebrew/science/opencv (required dependencies)
├── cmake
├── pkg-config
├── jpeg
├── libpng
|   └── xz
├── libtiff
|   └── jpeg
├── eigen
|   └── cmake
└── openexr
    ├── pkg-config
    └── ilmbase
```